# MySql query is slow with join - how to speed it up

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to export 554k records from our mysql db.  At the current rate it will take 5 days to export the data and the slowness is mainly caused by the query below.  The data structure consists of

```
Companies
--Contacts
----(Contact)Activities
```

For the contacts, we have an index on company_id.  On the activities table, we have an index for contact_id and company_id which map back to the respective contacts and companies tables.

I need to grab each contact and the latest activity date that they have.  This is the query that I'm running and it takes about .5 second to execute.

```
Select * 
from contacts 
left outer join (select  occurred_at
                        ,contact_id 
                 from activities 
                 where occurred_at is not null 
                 group by contact_id 
                 order by occurred_at desc) activities 
on contacts.id = activities.contact_id 
where company_id = 20
```

If I remove the join and just select * from contacts where company_id=20 the query executes in .016 sec.

If I use Explain for info on the join query I get this
[image]

Any ideas on how I can speed this up?

Edit:
Here are the table definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `falloff_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active_job_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `duplicate_of` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `warm_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dup_checked` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delinquent` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cconly` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_name` (`name`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_external_id` (`external_id`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_state_and_dup_checked` (`id`,`state`,`dup_checked`,`duplicate_of`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_dup_checked` (`id`,`dup_checked`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_dup_checked_name` (`dup_checked`,`name`),
  KEY `index_companies_on_county` (`county`,`state`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15190300 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `second_phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_contacts_on_company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `index_contacts_on_first_name` (`first_name`),
  KEY `index_contacts_on_last_name` (`last_name`),
  KEY `index_contacts_on_phone` (`phone`),
  KEY `index_contacts_on_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11241088 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `activities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kind` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occurred_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scheduled_for` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_activities_on_contact_id` (`contact_id`),
  KEY `index_activities_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `index_activities_on_company_id` (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=515340 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: You could remove the `order by` from the inner `select` for a start. It's pretty useless there. Some DB engines won't even allow `order by` in inner queries.

Comment: mypetition, I need the latest activity date so I need the order there.  Biansor, yes it has the indexes I mentioned in my intial post.

Comment: In query optimization questions, you should run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table and include the result in your question. Help us help you — you described some indexes, but if we want to copy your table to test it, it would help a lot to show us the complete table.

Comment: Table definitions added.

Comment: To get the latest activity date simply use `MAX(occurred_at)`

Comment: Doing that actually makes it slower.  Ordering returns in .469 seconds.  MAX(occurred_at) returns in .781

Comment: @geoffswartz that `order by` isn't necessarily getting you the latest activity date, order by is processed *after* `group by`; as dnoeth and some answers have indicated, MAX is what you need.

Comment: And do you actually try to run this query once for each company instead of a single Select? Ouch.

Comment: Yes.  I grab each company.  Then grab each contact for each company with the latest activity date for that specific contact.

Comment: Your working with a DBMS, write a single query to get the data for all companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query, which comes up frequently on Stack Overflow.

Here's a solution that uses a MySQL 8.0 window function:

```
WITH latest_activities AS (
  SELECT contact_id, occurred_at,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id ORDER BY occurred_at DESC) AS rn
  FROM activities
)
SELECT *
FROM contacts AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN latest_activities 
  ON c.id = latest_activities.contact_id AND latest_activities.rn = 1
WHERE c.company_id = 20
```

Here's a solution that should work on pre-8.0 versions:

```
SELECT c.*, a.*
FROM contacts AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN activities AS a ON a.contact_id = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN activities AS a2 ON a2.contact_id = c.id 
  AND a2.occurred_at > a.occurred_at
WHERE c.company_id = 20
  AND a2.contact_id IS NULL;
```

Another solution:

```
SELECT c.*, a.*
FROM contacts AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN activities AS a ON a.contact_id = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT c2.contact_id, MAX(a2.occurred_at) AS occurred_at
  FROM activities AS a2
  INNER JOIN contacts AS c2 ON a2.contact_id = c2.id
  WHERE c2.company_id = 20 
  GROUP BY c2.contact_id ORDER BY NULL
) AS latest_activities
  ON latest_activities.contact_id = c.id
  AND latest_activities.occurred_at = a.occurred_at
WHERE c.company_id = 20
```

It would be helpful to create a new index on activities (contact_id, occurred_at).

Comment: Thanks.  In your second solution it ends with a2.contact_id is null.  I don't understand that part.  Can you explain?

Comment: `a2`  is "activities that occurred after `a`", that final condition removes any results where there would have been activities later.

Comment: Right, the outer join should NOT match any row `a2` that has the same contact and a later activity date. We only want cases where `a` was the latest activity, which means the outer join will not find any that are later.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use subqueries in the `FROM` clause if you can help it.  They impede the MySQL optimizer.  So, if you want one row:

```
Select c.*, a.occurred_at
from contacts c left outer join
     from activities a
     on c.id = a.contact_id and
        a.occurred_at is not null 
where c.company_id = 20
order by a.occurred_at desc
limit 1;
```

If you want one row per `contact_id`:

```
Select c.*, a.occurred_at
from contacts c left outer join
     from activities a
     on c.id = a.contact_id and
        a.occurred_at is not null and
        a.occurred_at = (select max(a2.occurred_at)
                         from activities a2
                         where a2.contact_id = a.contact_id
                        )
where c.company_id = 20         
order by a.occurred_at desc
limit 1;
```

This can make use of an index on `activities(contact_id, occured_at)`. and `contact(company_id, contact_id)`.

Your query is doing one thing that is a clear no-no -- and no longer supported by the default settings in the most recent versions of MySQL.  You have unaggregated columns in a `select` that are not in the `group by`.  The `contact_id` should be generating an error.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I am overlooking something with how complicated the other answers are, but I would think this would be all you need.

```
SELECT c.*
   , MAX(a.occurred_at) AS occurred_at
FROM contacts AS c
LEFT JOIN activities AS a
   ON c.id = a.contact_id AND a.occurred_at IS NOT NULL
WHERE c.company_id = 20
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Notes: (1) this assumes you didn't actually want the duplicate contact_id from your original subquery to be in the final results. (2) This also assumes your server is not configured to require a full group by; if it is, you will need to manually expand `c.*` into the full column list, and copy that list to the `GROUP BY` clause as well.

---

Expanding on dnoeth's comments to your question; if you are not querying each company separately for a particular reason (*chunking for load, code structure handling this also handles other stuff company by company, whatever)*, you could tweak the above query like so to get all your results in one query.

```
SELECT con.*
   , MAX(a.occurred_at) AS occurred_at
FROM companies AS com 
INNER JOIN contacts AS con ON com.id = con.company_id
LEFT JOIN activities AS a
   ON con.id = a.contact_id AND a.occurred_at IS NOT NULL
WHERE [criteria for companies chosen to be queried]
GROUP BY con.id
ORDER BY con.company_id, con.id
;
```

Comment: That won't get any of the other columns from the activity that was the latest activity. It only gets the date of the latest activity. If you try to include `a.*` it won't necessarily return values from the row where the latest date was found.

Comment: @BillKarwin wasn't he only looking for the last activity date?

Comment: The original query used `Select *` so I assumed that details about the respective latest activity might be needed.

Comment: Ah yeah, the subquery included in that select * would have only returned the latest occurred_by for each contact_id and contact_id that was redundant in the `*` (or at least it was intended to return the latest occurred_by).